# MediaManager video playing when component is created

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to have the video player NOT start playing video the moment it is created, and let the user choose to play it through the native controls?

```
Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
Media video = com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(url, true);
video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
video.pause(); // <-- not doing anything
container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, video.getVideoComponent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the build hint `ios.enableAutoplayVideo=false` to disable that OS specific behavior on iOS. The pause approach might work after the form is shown and `isPlaying()` returns `true`.

Comment: I added this to the build hint, but it still auto plays

Comment: Yes, The videos were not playing at all on other devices.

Comment: We'll need to look into it, this might be related to this iOS behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396032/mpmovieplayercontroller-autoplays-when-streaming-how-do-i-stop-it I suggest filing an issue so we can track it